# Where to add custom.less file in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less

It sounds ridiculous but I cannot find where to add my style.less file in Bootstrap.

I have :

1. Installed Node
2. Installed Bower (npm install -g bower=
3. Installed Boostrap (bower install bootstrap --save
4. Created a style.less file into bower_components\bootstrap\less with this code :

   ```
   @import "bootstrap.less",@import "variables.less";    @import "mixins.less";       
       body {
         background:#fff;
         font-family: 'eau_doucesans_regular', sans-serif;
       }
   ```
5. Then I launch grunt watch, made a modification to my file style.less and I received this output in my terminal :

grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...

> > File "less\style.less" changed.
> >     Running "less:compileCore" (less) task
> >     1 stylesheet created.
> >     1 sourcemap created.

Running "less:compileTheme" (less) task

> > 1 stylesheet created.
> >     1 sourcemap created.

Done.

But I cannot find any modification in my dist/css folder...

What do I do wrong ?

This is the content of my gruntfile.js :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
'use strict';

// Force use of Unix newlines
grunt.util.linefeed = '\n';

RegExp.quote = function(string) {
    return string.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var generateGlyphiconsData = require('./grunt/bs-glyphicons-data-generator.js');
var BsLessdocParser = require('./grunt/bs-lessdoc-parser.js');
var getLessVarsData = function() {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'less/variables.less');
    var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {
        encoding: 'utf8'
    });
    var parser = new BsLessdocParser(fileContent);
    return {
        sections: parser.parseFile()
    };
};
var generateRawFiles = require('./grunt/bs-raw-files-generator.js');
var generateCommonJSModule = require('./grunt/bs-commonjs-generator.js');
var configBridge = grunt.file.readJSON('./grunt/configBridge.json', {
    encoding: 'utf8'
});

Object.keys(configBridge.paths).forEach(function(key) {
    configBridge.paths[key].forEach(function(val, i, arr) {
        arr[i] = path.join('./docs/assets', val);
    });
});

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

    // Metadata.
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    banner: '/*!\n' +
        ' * Bootstrap v<%= pkg.version %> (<%= pkg.homepage %>)\n' +
        ' * Copyright 2011-<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author %>\n' +
        ' * Licensed under the <%= pkg.license %> license\n' +
        ' */\n',
    jqueryCheck: configBridge.config.jqueryCheck.join('\n'),
    jqueryVersionCheck: configBridge.config.jqueryVersionCheck.join('\n'),

    // Task configuration.
    clean: {
        dist: 'dist',
        docs: 'docs/dist'
    },

    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: 'js/.jshintrc'
        },
        grunt: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: 'grunt/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'package.js', 'grunt/*.js']
        },
        core: {
            src: 'js/*.js'
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: 'js/tests/unit/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: 'js/tests/unit/*.js'
        },
        assets: {
            src: ['docs/assets/js/src/*.js', 'docs/assets/js/*.js', '!docs/assets/js/*.min.js']
        }
    },

    jscs: {
        options: {
            config: 'js/.jscsrc'
        },
        grunt: {
            src: '<%= jshint.grunt.src %>'
        },
        core: {
            src: '<%= jshint.core.src %>'
        },
        test: {
            src: '<%= jshint.test.src %>'
        },
        assets: {
            options: {
                requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers: null
            },
            src: '<%= jshint.assets.src %>'
        }
    },

    concat: {
        options: {
            banner: '<%= banner %>\n<%= jqueryCheck %>\n<%= jqueryVersionCheck %>',
            stripBanners: false
        },
        bootstrap: {
            src: [
                'js/transition.js',
                'js/alert.js',
                'js/button.js',
                'js/carousel.js',
                'js/collapse.js',
                'js/dropdown.js',
                'js/modal.js',
                'js/tooltip.js',
                'js/popover.js',
                'js/scrollspy.js',
                'js/tab.js',
                'js/affix.js'
            ],
            dest: 'dist/js/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        options: {
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            mangle: true,
            preserveComments: /^!|@preserve|@license|@cc_on/i
        },
        core: {
            src: '<%= concat.bootstrap.dest %>',
            dest: 'dist/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
        },
        customize: {
            src: configBridge.paths.customizerJs,
            dest: 'docs/assets/js/customize.min.js'
        },
        docsJs: {
            src: configBridge.paths.docsJs,
            dest: 'docs/assets/js/docs.min.js'
        }
    },

    qunit: {
        options: {
            inject: 'js/tests/unit/phantom.js'
        },
        files: 'js/tests/index.html'
    },

    less: {
        compileCore: {
            options: {
                strictMath: true,
                sourceMap: true,
                outputSourceFiles: true,
                sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
                sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
            },
            src: 'less/bootstrap.less',
            dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css'
        },
        compileTheme: {
            options: {
                strictMath: true,
                sourceMap: true,
                outputSourceFiles: true,
                sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map',
                sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map'
            },
            src: 'less/theme.less',
            dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
        }
    },

    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: configBridge.config.autoprefixerBrowsers
        },
        core: {
            options: {
                map: true
            },
            src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css'
        },
        theme: {
            options: {
                map: true
            },
            src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
        },
        docs: {
            src: ['docs/assets/css/src/docs.css']
        },
        examples: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'docs/examples/',
            src: ['**/*.css'],
            dest: 'docs/examples/'
        }
    },

    csslint: {
        options: {
            csslintrc: 'less/.csslintrc'
        },
        dist: [
            'dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
        ],
        examples: [
            'docs/examples/**/*.css'
        ],
        docs: {
            options: {
                ids: false,
                'overqualified-elements': false
            },
            src: 'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css'
        }
    },

    cssmin: {
        options: {
            // TODO: disable `zeroUnits` optimization once clean-css 3.2 is released
            //    and then simplify the fix for https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14837 accordingly
            compatibility: 'ie8',
            keepSpecialComments: '*',
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapInlineSources: true,
            advanced: false
        },
        minifyCore: {
            src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css',
            dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.min.css'
        },
        minifyTheme: {
            src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css',
            dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.min.css'
        },
        docs: {
            src: [
                'docs/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css',
                'docs/assets/css/src/pygments-manni.css',
                'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css'
            ],
            dest: 'docs/assets/css/docs.min.css'
        }
    },

    csscomb: {
        options: {
            config: 'less/.csscomb.json'
        },
        dist: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'dist/css/',
            src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
            dest: 'dist/css/'
        },
        examples: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'docs/examples/',
            src: '**/*.css',
            dest: 'docs/examples/'
        },
        docs: {
            src: 'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css',
            dest: 'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css'
        }
    },

    copy: {
        fonts: {
            expand: true,
            src: 'fonts/**',
            dest: 'dist/'
        },
        docs: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'dist/',
            src: [
                '**/*'
            ],
            dest: 'docs/dist/'
        }
    },

    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                port: 3000,
                base: '.'
            }
        }
    },

    jekyll: {
        options: {
            bundleExec: true,
            config: '_config.yml',
            incremental: false
        },
        docs: {},
        github: {
            options: {
                raw: 'github: true'
            }
        }
    },

    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                conservativeCollapse: true,
                decodeEntities: false,
                minifyCSS: {
                    compatibility: 'ie8',
                    keepSpecialComments: 0
                },
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyURLs: false,
                processConditionalComments: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeOptionalAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                removeTagWhitespace: false,
                sortAttributes: true,
                sortClassName: true
            },
            expand: true,
            cwd: '_gh_pages',
            dest: '_gh_pages',
            src: [
                '**/*.html',
                '!examples/**/*.html'
            ]
        }
    },

    pug: {
        options: {
            pretty: true,
            data: getLessVarsData
        },
        customizerVars: {
            src: 'docs/_pug/customizer-variables.pug',
            dest: 'docs/_includes/customizer-variables.html'
        },
        customizerNav: {
            src: 'docs/_pug/customizer-nav.pug',
            dest: 'docs/_includes/nav/customize.html'
        }
    },

    htmllint: {
        options: {
            ignore: [
                'Attribute "autocomplete" not allowed on element "button" at this point.',
                'Attribute "autocomplete" is only allowed when the input type is "color", "date", "datetime", "datetime-local", "email", "hidden", "month", "number", "password", "range", "search", "tel", "text", "time", "url", or "week".',
                'Element "img" is missing required attribute "src".'
            ]
        },
        src: '_gh_pages/**/*.html'
    },

    watch: {
        src: {
            files: '<%= jshint.core.src %>',
            tasks: ['jshint:core', 'qunit', 'concat']
        },
        test: {
            files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
            tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
        },
        less: {
            files: 'less/**/*.less',
            tasks: 'less'
        }
    },

    'saucelabs-qunit': {
        all: {
            options: {
                build: process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_ID,
                throttled: 10,
                maxRetries: 3,
                maxPollRetries: 4,
                urls: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/tests/index.html?hidepassed'],
                browsers: grunt.file.readYAML('grunt/sauce_browsers.yml')
            }
        }
    },

    exec: {
        npmUpdate: {
            command: 'npm update'
        }
    },

    compress: {
        main: {
            options: {
                archive: 'bootstrap-<%= pkg.version %>-dist.zip',
                mode: 'zip',
                level: 9,
                pretty: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'dist/',
                src: ['**'],
                dest: 'bootstrap-<%= pkg.version %>-dist'
            }]
        }
    }

});


// These plugins provide necessary tasks.
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, {
    scope: 'devDependencies'
});
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Docs HTML validation task
grunt.registerTask('validate-html', ['jekyll:docs', 'htmllint']);

var runSubset = function(subset) {
    return !process.env.TWBS_TEST || process.env.TWBS_TEST === subset;
};
var isUndefOrNonZero = function(val) {
    return val === undefined || val !== '0';
};

// Test task.
var testSubtasks = [];
// Skip core tests if running a different subset of the test suite
if (runSubset('core') &&
    // Skip core tests if this is a Savage build
    process.env.TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG !== 'twbs-savage/bootstrap') {
    testSubtasks = testSubtasks.concat(['dist-css', 'dist-js', 'csslint:dist', 'test-js', 'docs']);
}
// Skip HTML validation if running a different subset of the test suite
if (runSubset('validate-html') &&
    // Skip HTML5 validator on Travis when [skip validator] is in the commit message
    isUndefOrNonZero(process.env.TWBS_DO_VALIDATOR)) {
    testSubtasks.push('validate-html');
}
// Only run Sauce Labs tests if there's a Sauce access key
if (typeof process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY !== 'undefined' &&
    // Skip Sauce if running a different subset of the test suite
    runSubset('sauce-js-unit') &&
    // Skip Sauce on Travis when [skip sauce] is in the commit message
    isUndefOrNonZero(process.env.TWBS_DO_SAUCE)) {
    testSubtasks.push('connect');
    testSubtasks.push('saucelabs-qunit');
}
grunt.registerTask('test', testSubtasks);
grunt.registerTask('test-js', ['jshint:core', 'jshint:test', 'jshint:grunt', 'jscs:core', 'jscs:test', 'jscs:grunt', 'qunit']);

// JS distribution task.
grunt.registerTask('dist-js', ['concat', 'uglify:core', 'commonjs']);

// CSS distribution task.
grunt.registerTask('less-compile', ['less:compileCore', 'less:compileTheme']);
grunt.registerTask('dist-css', ['less-compile', 'autoprefixer:core', 'autoprefixer:theme', 'csscomb:dist', 'cssmin:minifyCore', 'cssmin:minifyTheme']);

// Full distribution task.
grunt.registerTask('dist', ['clean:dist', 'dist-css', 'copy:fonts', 'dist-js']);

// Default task.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean:dist', 'copy:fonts', 'test']);

grunt.registerTask('build-glyphicons-data', function() {
    generateGlyphiconsData.call(this, grunt);
});

// task for building customizer
grunt.registerTask('build-customizer', ['build-customizer-html', 'build-raw-files']);
grunt.registerTask('build-customizer-html', 'pug');
grunt.registerTask('build-raw-files', 'Add scripts/less files to customizer.', function() {
    var banner = grunt.template.process('<%= banner %>');
    generateRawFiles(grunt, banner);
});

grunt.registerTask('commonjs', 'Generate CommonJS entrypoint module in dist dir.', function() {
    var srcFiles = grunt.config.get('concat.bootstrap.src');
    var destFilepath = 'dist/js/npm.js';
    generateCommonJSModule(grunt, srcFiles, destFilepath);
});

// Docs task.
grunt.registerTask('docs-css', ['autoprefixer:docs', 'autoprefixer:examples', 'csscomb:docs', 'csscomb:examples', 'cssmin:docs']);
grunt.registerTask('lint-docs-css', ['csslint:docs', 'csslint:examples']);
grunt.registerTask('docs-js', ['uglify:docsJs', 'uglify:customize']);
grunt.registerTask('lint-docs-js', ['jshint:assets', 'jscs:assets']);
grunt.registerTask('docs', ['docs-css', 'lint-docs-css', 'docs-js', 'lint-docs-js', 'clean:docs', 'copy:docs', 'build-glyphicons-data', 'build-customizer']);
grunt.registerTask('docs-github', ['jekyll:github', 'htmlmin']);

grunt.registerTask('prep-release', ['dist', 'docs', 'docs-github', 'compress']);
};
```

Comment: Can you share your `gruntfile.js` please? It should be found in your root directory of your project. e.g. here is an example one. https://github.com/harrymt/grunt-boilerplate/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Comment: You need a semicolon `;` not a `,` in `@import "bootstrap.less",`